# Save file names from S3 location in an array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have S3 location like `s3://bucket-name/folder-parquet/`.
I want to get all the file names from this location and save it in an array.

So if we have files like `part-0000.parquet`, `part-0001.parquet` at `s3://bucket-name/folder-parquet/` then my array should like:

```
array = ['part-0000.parquet','part-0001.parquet']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use official [aws sdk library](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) or [scala specific library](https://index.scala-lang.org/bizreach/aws-s3-scala/aws-s3-scala/0.0.15?target=_2.12).

Here is the solution using s3-scala library:

```
  import jp.co.bizreach.s3scala.S3
  import awscala.Region

  implicit val region = Region.Mumbai
  implicit val s3 = S3(accessKeyId = "accessKeyId", secretAccessKey = "secretAccessKey")
  val bucketName = "bucketName"
  val folderName = "folderName" // s3 object
  val filePathList = s3.bucket(bucketName).get.keys(s"$folderName/").toList
  val fileNameList = filePathList.map(_.replace(s"$folderName/", "")).drop(1)
  println(fileNameList)
```